# Android Dev - Custom List View Not showning all children components

Tags: android, android-listview, android-emulator, baseadapter

I have a wiered problem I have a custom list implementation which is working properly in most of devices , **But only in few device like galaxy s4 or grand duos,** The last image of child element is not visible.

the code is as below..

Main List View :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundimage"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Child Element Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/App_Name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_image"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:text="Rihanna Love the way lie"
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:textSize="12dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/App_Desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/App_Name"
                android:layout_below="@+id/App_Name"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:text="Just gona stand there and ..."
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:textSize="10dip"
                android:typeface="monospace" />
        </LinearLayout>
            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Price"
        android:layout_width="20dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/buy_gas" />

     </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter code

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BinderData extends BaseAdapter {

    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_TAG = "weatherdata"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_CITY = "city";
    static final String KEY_TEMP_C = "tempc";
    static final String KEY_TEMP_F = "tempf";
    static final String KEY_CONDN = "condition";
    static final String KEY_SPEED = "windspeed";
    static final String KEY_ICON = "icon";

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageView thumb_image;
    List<HashMap<String,String>> weatherDataCollection;
    ViewHolder holder;
    public BinderData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public BinderData(Activity act, List<HashMap<String,String>> map) {

        this.weatherDataCollection = map;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      return idlist.size();
        return weatherDataCollection.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null){

          vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
          holder = new ViewHolder();

          holder.tvCity = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.App_Name); // city name
          holder.tvWeather = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.App_Desc); // city weather overview
          holder.tvTemperature =  (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.Price); // city temperature
          holder.tvWeatherImage =(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

          vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{

            holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        }

          // Setting all values in listview

          holder.tvCity.setText(weatherDataCollection.get(position).get("App_Name"));
          holder.tvWeather.setText(weatherDataCollection.get(position).get("App_Desc"));
          String uri = "";
          if(weatherDataCollection.get(position).get("Price").equalsIgnoreCase("pro"))
          {
              uri = "drawable/label";

          }else{
              uri = "drawable/free";
          }
          int imageResource = vi.getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, vi.getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
          Drawable image = vi.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
          holder.tvTemperature.setImageDrawable(image);
          //holder.tvTemperature.setText(weatherDataCollection.get(position).get("Price"));

          //Setting an image
          String uri2 = "drawable/"+ weatherDataCollection.get(position).get("image_url");
          int imageResource2 = vi.getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(uri2, null, vi.getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
          Drawable image2 = vi.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(imageResource2);
          holder.tvWeatherImage.setImageDrawable(image2);

          return vi;
    }

    /*
     * 
     * */
    static class ViewHolder{

        TextView tvCity;
        ImageView tvTemperature;
        TextView tvWeather;
        ImageView tvWeatherImage;
    }

}
```

List View Implementation:

```
  BinderData bindingData = new BinderData(this,songsList);
                list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

                list.setAdapter(bindingData);
```

Please help us on this..

Comment: could you please add you listview class and its adapter class

Comment: Addeed.. please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Try this Child Element code. It worked for me!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/App_Name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:text="Rihanna Love the way lie"
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:textSize="12dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" 
                android:layout_gravity="center|left"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/App_Desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:text="Just gona stand there and ..."
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:textSize="10dip"
                android:typeface="monospace"
                android:layout_gravity="center|left"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Price"
        android:layout_width="20dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:src="@drawable/buy_gas" />

     </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No Hari Not Working ... I think its some thing related to density.. Try running it on samsung galaxy s4 or s4 simuator.. The right most image is not showing up

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED :

The problem was with the right most icon, It was having very high resolution just reduced the resolution and replaced the Files and it worked.

Thanks every one for their time..